# Compiling cowpatty on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit fails

Tags: openssl

So, I downloaded cowpatty from their site[1] and I am trying to compile it. However, there is an error that prevents the make-process.

```
root@phil-laptop:/home/phil/wifite-2.0r85/cowpatty-4.6# make
cc -pipe -Wall -DOPENSSL  -O2 -g3 -ggdb   -c -o md5.o md5.c
md5.c:20:25: fatal error: openssl/md5.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/md5.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [md5.o] Error 1
```

OpenSSL is installed on this system. Any advice?

Thanks!

[1] http://wirelessdefence.org/Contents/coWPAttyMain.htm#Installing_coWPAtty:

Comment: is the libssl-_dev_ package installed?

Answer (score 5):

After looking at the cowpatty Makefile:

```
LDLIBS   = -lpcap
CFLAGS   = -pipe -Wall -DOPENSSL 
LDLIBS  += -lcrypto
```

I'd suggest you to install the following *development* packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev libssl-dev
```